# How does an hybridised orbital become unhybridised after bond cleavage?

Tags: hybridization

In $\ce{CH4}$, $1 s$ and $3 p$ orbitals are hybridised into four $sp^3$ orbitals. But on homolytic bond cleavage an unpaired electron remains in an unhybridised $p$ orbital?

Similarly in heterolytic bond cleavage of $\ce{CH4}$, the methyl carbocation has an unhybridised empty $p$ orbital?

Comment: We have had this confusion many times before. See [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31973/what-does-it-mean-when-it-is-said-that-an-sp%C2%B3-orbital-has-25-s-character?rq=1) for some detail. **Hybridisation is simply a mathematical quirk to make valence bond theory work better.** It doesn't exist in the real world. In methane, the atomic orbitals overlap to form a set of molecular orbitals. $sp^3$ orbitals do not come into the final bonding description of methane (at least in the MO theory version).